# Unable to write "undefined" file in grunt plugin

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, npm

I'm new to writing grunt plugins and I'm running into a problem when I'm trying to run it:

```
Running "inject_css:dev" (inject_css) task
Warning: Unable to write "undefined" file (Error code: undefined). Use --force to continue.
```

My plugin looks like:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.registerMultiTask('inject_css', 'Allows you to inject CSS into HTML files as part of the build process.', function() {
    var src = grunt.file.expand(this.data.src);
    var text = '';

    if (src) {
        src.forEach(function (script) {
            text += grunt.file.read(script);
        });
    } else {
        grunt.log.error('Please specify a file to inject into the html.');
        return;
    }

    this.files.forEach(function (file) {
        grunt.file.write(file.dest, grunt.file.read(file.src).replace('<!-- inject -->', '<style type="text/css">' + text + '</style>'));
        grunt.log.ok('File injected'.blue + ' into ' + file.dest);
    });
  });
};
```

And when trying to call it in my gruntfile I'm using the following config:

```
inject_css: {
  dev: {
    files:{
      'static/test/test.html': 'test.html'
    },
    src: 'static/less/form.less'
  }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the warning, I'm guessing it is thrown there :

```
grunt.file.write(file.dest, grunt.file.read(file.src).replace('<!-- inject -->', '<style type="text/css">' + text + '</style>'));
```

Which would mean `file.dest` is undefined.

And looking at your code, it seems normal cause you go with a foreach over `this.files` which do not contain any `dest` property.

Basically, I think you forgot to expand `this.dest` and this should do the trick :

```
var expandedFiles = grunt.file.expand(this.data.files);
expandedFiles.forEach(function (file) {
    grunt.file.write(file.dest, grunt.file.read(file.src).replace('<!-- inject -->', '<style type="text/css">' + text + '</style>'));
    grunt.log.ok('File injected'.blue + ' into ' + file.dest);
});
```

As i couldn't really try it, it's just a guess, let me know if it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
inject_css: {
  dev: {
    .....
    src: ['static/less/form.less']
  }
}
```